# Как сформировать JSON из SQL-таблицы?

Tags: javascript, sql, json, sqlite

Есть SQL-таблица `messages` (использую `sqlite3`), нужно всё её содержимое передать в переменную в виде `JSON`.

Делаю так:

```
allJSON = db.run("SELECT * 
            FROM messages
           FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('messages')");
```

но это не работает, `allJSON` равен `Database {}`, его тип - `object`, хотя ожидаемый JSON должен
выглядеть примерно так:

```
{
 messages:
    [
     {
  message: {"msg":"agFhOJebvGVoBZNwn+d91B8MF+5gG6XEabqb2+ZRJwKKSA==","mac":{"words":[1452474577,-67406655,-1284086449,1113589958,1060686933,-1978451101,1625364159,1849138338],"sigBytes":32}
  coordinates: { coords: [ 54.99099679698505, 82.94283974609368 ], radius: '10000' },
  login: 'qwe',
  password: 'qwe'
     }
    ],
//остальные message
}
```

как это исправить?

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: Странно, но документация по SQLite утверждает, что про `SELECT .. FOR JSON` она ничего не знает... https://www.sqlite.org/search?s=d&q=%22FOR+JSON%22 `SELECT .. FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('messages')` - это синтаксис SQL Server.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, буду внимательнее

Comment: В sqlite придётся конструировать результат с помощью [JSON Functions And Operators](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html). Что-то наподобие: `SELECT json_object('Id', Id, 'Name', Name) FROM table;` используя вложенные `json_object` и `json_group_array` где надо.